# Editing gas price to limite contract deployment cost?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, gas-price, truffle-deployment

My smart contract costs 3.65 USD to deploy from `truffle-cli`. I wish to accomplish this in 2.5 USD. Is it possible to limit the gas price in `gwei` in `truffle-config.js` to accomplish this? I don't mind waiting for it to deploy.Gas prices are relatively low right now ([6 gwei](https://ethgasstation.info/)).

I have accomplished this on Rinkeby Testnet.

Or is this futile ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the gas price to be whatever you want - even 0. But the used gas price influences directly when your transaction gets included in a block.

If you use too low gas price, the transaction will most likely not be included. Unfortunately, nobody can tell you what is the lowest price with which it will get included within, for example, a week.

If your price is too low, the transaction will stay in the mempool (node transaction buffer) for a while but it will be simply discarded at some point and it's like you had never even sent it. Of maybe no node will even accept it in their mempool.